# why is my yaml invalid in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am seeing this error in Jenkins (running ansible playbook).

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: mapping values are not allowed here
in "<unicode string>", line 6, column 9:
  - name: Remove package
        ^
```

playbook.yml

```
---

## Update package

- tasks
  - name: Remove package
    shell: aws s3 rm s3://pipeline-dev/packages/first_package.zip --sse --debug

  - name: Update package
    shell: aws s3 cp ./packages/package.zip s3://pipeline-dev/packages/first_package.zip --sse --debug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a root level sequence in your YAML document, for which the first item is `tasks`

Directly following is an indented node, which has no parent. You probably need to add a value indicator character (`:`) after `tasks`

```
- tasks:
  - name: Remove package
    shell: aws s3 rm s3://pipeline-dev/packages/first_package.zip --sse --debug
```

So that tasks will be a key, for which the value is the sequence for which the items (not the item indicator) is indented four positions.